How to specify column parameters programmatically?
For the qic() function, how does one specify columns of the input data frame that are stored in string variables?
Below I attempt multiple ways to pass the "y" parameter.  Given that qicharts2 is based on ggplot2 I tried some options resembling quoting for ggplot2.  All failed.
my_fun <- function(y){
  require(qicharts2)

  qic(x        = i, 
      y        = .data[[y]],  # Hoping it works like ggplot2.
      n        = n, 
      data     = nhs_accidents, 
      chart    = 'p',
      title    = 'Proportion of patients seen within 4 hours',
      ylab     = NULL,
      xlab     = 'Week #')
}

my_var <- "r"
my_fun(my_var)


Error: ! Can't subset .data outside of a data mask context. Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

Here are some other ways I tried to define the parameter along with the errors.
y = as.symbol(my_var)

Error in stats::complete.cases(y, n) :    invalid 'type' (symbol) of argument

y = {{my_var}}

Error in if (y.name == "NULL") y.name <- deparse(substitute(x)) : the condition has length > 1

y = rlang::as_label(my_var)

Error in stats::complete.cases(y, n) : not all arguments have the same length


Why not use nhs_accidents[[y]] instead of .data[[.y]]? Or perhaps use function(y, data) and use data[[.y]]?

Not sure how to select best of the two submitted answers.  They satisfy the question in fundamentally different ways.  One makes use of variable evaluation within the data context while the other restates the context.  Wondering if there is reason to prefer one over the other.  Perhaps one would be expected to be faster at scale.

This works for me:
my_fun <- function(y_){
  require(qicharts2)
  qic(x        = i, 
      y        = eval(parse(text = y_)),
      n        = n, 
      data     = nhs_accidents, 
      chart    = 'p',
      title    = 'Proportion of patients seen within 4 hours',
      ylab     = NULL,
      xlab     = 'Week #')
}

my_var <- "r"

my_fun(my_var)


To specify columns programmatically in qicharts2, you can use dplyr::pull() to pull the required column from the data frame by its name. Here's how you can adjust your my_fun() function:
my_fun <- function(y){
  require(dplyr)
  require(qicharts2)
  qic(x        = i, 
      y        = nhs_accidents %>% pull(y),  # Pulls the column based on the string
      n        = n, 
      data     = nhs_accidents, 
      chart    = 'p',
      title    = 'Proportion of patients seen within 4 hours',
      ylab     = NULL,
      xlab     = 'Week #')
}

This should resolve the error you're encountering. dplyr::pull() allows you to programmatically refer to columns using string names.
